# Microsoft Ajax CDN doesn't include MicrosoftMvcAjax.js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I try to reference my java script file from Microsoft Ajax CDN , but find out that Microsoft Ajax CDN doesn't include MicrosoftMvcAjax.js.

Is there an undocumented way to include those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks Microsoft added ajax file to its CDN hosting later.